# Local computer policy not working

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-registry, group-policy

[The policy appears in gpresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OwdQ.png)

I have a domain-joined computer that I'm trying to add a local policy to end RDP sessions after being disconnected for a certain amount of time. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly but I've tried adding the registry key MaxDisconnectionTime, in "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" and I can see it in regedit. I set it to one minute to test it, but the RDP session does not seem to end after that time has passed. Why could this be and how do I fix it? Keep in mind   I have no previous experience with this, and I don't want to add this feature through AD, it has to be local.

Comment: How is the domain policy set?  Does it create a conflict with the local policy?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the local group policy editor instead, then navigating this path

Computer Configuration, Admin Templates, Windows Components, Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Session Host, Session Time Limits.

Once done, run cmd command gpupdate /force to push the new gp config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this method as well and it seems to have no effect as well, even though the policy does seem to apply according to gpresult

Comment: Have you tried running it through the user config rather than computer, to see if it makes a difference? or check to see if there is any GPO that is attached to the OU of the domain that takes precedence over the LGPO. I know there are certain hierarchical elements.

Comment: I have now tried doing it through user config and it shows up in gpresult and rsop.msc, still seems to have no effect on the RDP session. It doesn't seem like there's any GPO that has precedence directly over the LGPO either. The only GPO I could find on the PDC related to session time limits was one that enables the screensaver after a certain amount of time. for some reason the RDP session completely ignores my local policies.